# Weevely on windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

i'm getting an error while installing Weevely on Windows 7 
I'm a Python newbie :/

```
C:\Python27\weevely>python weevely.py generate testmypwd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weevely.py", line 108, in <module>
    Terminal (ModHandler(genname, password), True).run_module_cmd(args_list)
  File "C:\Python27\weevely\core\modules_handler.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.__set_path_modules()
  File "C:\Python27\weevely\core\modules_handler.py", line 42, in __set_path_modules
    raise Exception( "No module directory %s found." % self.path_modules )
Exception: No module directory /modules found.
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Does your file C:\Python27\weevely\core\modules_handler.py has line no. 36 as:-

> root_path = '/'.join(current_path.split('/')[:-2]) + '/'

Comment: Yes the line no. 36 is

    root_path = '/'.join(current_path.split('/')[:-2]) + '/'

Comment: Then, this means that the package that you have is not windows compatible. You should be using it on Linux/Unix boxes. You can try 1 thing. Change the line no. 36 to be windows specific. Not sure though in might break somewhere else where hard-coding of the os path separator is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the basic problem is that this module is to be run on Linux/Unix (noticed because the weevely.py is invoking the shebang line: `#!/usr/bin/env python`), but, WebJuice is trying to run on Windows, I tried changing the lines 36 and 37 of file: C:\Python27\weevely\core\modules_handler.py to the following:

```
root_path = os.path.dirname(current_path)
self.path_modules = os.path.join(root_path,'modules')
```

But, still there is other dependent module: readline, which is not available for Windows (as evident from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/readline/), and you never know if there are more unseen linux related dependencies. So, I would conclude that we can not run this on Windows.

**PS**: I am referring to the weevely package I downloaded from http://cloud.github.com/downloads/epinna/Weevely/weevely-0.7.1.tar.gz. However, if someone finds an equivalent linux package, please post the URL for that.

Comment: Ok thnaks, i've installed backbox much more better now :)

Answer (score 0):

From version 1.0 Weevely supports officially Windows and MacOS enviroinments, as written in the tutorial.

https://github.com/epinna/Weevely/wiki/Tutorial

Download it from the official site http://epinna.github.com/Weevely/